# Свойство "Content" задано несколько раз

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Button  Content="{l:Localization Key=Name}" >
    <Image Source="Images/Copy.png" Height="32"/>
</Button>
```

> Свойство "Content" задано несколько раз.

Как добавить одновременно надпись `Content="{l:Localization Key=Name}"` и картинку?

Так не помогло:

```
<Button.Background>
    <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Images/Copy.png" />
</Button.Background>
```

Так появилась картинка но исчез текст

```
<Button.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="Images/Copy.png"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Button.ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так помогло

```
<Button.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                                      
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Images/Copy.png" Margin="-100,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Button.ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `Content` в классах WPF это *свойство содержимого*, значением которого является содержимое XML элемента.  Для таких свойств имеется специальное соглашение. Т.е. свойство `Content` можно задать нескольким способами. Например запись вида:

```
<Button Content="123">   

</Button>
```

равносильна записи:

```
<Button>   
    123
</Button>
```

или можно задать значение так:

```
<Button>   
    <Button.Content>
         <TextBlock Text="123"/>
    </Button.Content> 
</Button>
```

> Как добавить одновременно надпись Content="{l:Localization Key=Name}" и картинку?

```
<Button>   
    <Button.Content>
         <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
             <Image Source="{Binding }"/>
         </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content> 
</Button>
```

P.S. Информация почерпнута из книги Адама Натана *WPF4 Подробное руководство*.

Comment: Твой вариант работать не будет тк один Content уже есть `Content="{l:Localization Key=Name}"`

Comment: Если у вас задано 2 Contentа то да. Смысл ответа был в том что Content можно задать один раз, поэтому у вас и была проблема: "Свойство "Content" задано несколько раз."